# Getting Cross Origin Error While Calling API From Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jquery-ajaxq

I Got Following Error While Calling API From AJAX Jquery.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://www.demo.in/rest/employee/mapping/v3/9714620362' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8191' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

I don't have Access To Change API Coding. I just have API call  From javascript or Jquery.
I used Following Code For Calling  REST API.But I is not Working.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.demo.in/rest/employee/mapping/v3/9714620362',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function(data){
          console.log('succes: '+data);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Update the dataType to "jsonp" and it should work

`$.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.demo.in/rest/employee/mapping/v3/9714620362',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: '',
        success: function(data){
          console.log('succes: '+data);
        }
      });`

Comment: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.demo.in/rest/employee/mapping/v3/9714620362?callback=jQuery21009136693695828135_1543216490523&_=1543216490524 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: In that case use CORS Anywhere
CORS Anywhere is a node.js proxy which adds CORS support
To use the API, just prefix the URL with the API URL.
To enable cross-domain requests when needed, use the following snippet: `https://codeshare.io/5OXOJj`

Comment: `been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`